# Error 1064 de MySql: creado con MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy intentando exportar un modelo a mysql pero al momento de exportarlo me aparece lo siguiente en una de las tablas:

> ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '
>   INDEX `fk_Ventas_Cliente1_idx` (`Cliente_idBecados` ASC) VISIBLE,
>   INDEX `fk' at line 11

```
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Ventas` (
          `idVentas` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `Fecha` DATE NULL,
          `Hora` TIME NULL,
          `Nota` VARCHAR(500) NULL,
          `totalVenta` FLOAT NULL,
          `Empleados_idEmpleados` INT NOT NULL,
          `Cliente_idBecados` INT NOT NULL,
          `Usuarios_idUsuarios` INT NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`idVentas`),
          INDEX `fk_Ventas_Empleados1_idx` (`Empleados_idEmpleados` ASC) VISIBLE,
          INDEX `fk_Ventas_Cliente1_idx` (`Cliente_idBecados` ASC) VISIBLE,
          INDEX `fk_Ventas_Usuarios1_idx` (`Usuarios_idUsuarios` ASC) VISIBLE,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_Ventas_Empleados1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`Empleados_idEmpleados`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`Empleados` (`idEmpleados`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_Ventas_Cliente1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`Cliente_idBecados`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`Cliente` (`idBecados`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_Ventas_Usuarios1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`Usuarios_idUsuarios`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`Usuarios` (`idUsuarios`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De acuerdo con [la documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/invisible-indexes.html), los índices tienen una naturaleza visible por *default*, entonces basta con remover dicho atributo y dejarlo así:

```
      INDEX `fk_Ventas_Empleados1_idx` (`Empleados_idEmpleados` ASC),
      INDEX `fk_Ventas_Cliente1_idx` (`Cliente_idBecados` ASC),
      INDEX `fk_Ventas_Usuarios1_idx` (`Usuarios_idUsuarios` ASC),
```

Por otro lado el atributo que si debes declarar si deseas un comportamiento disitnto es `INVISIBLE`; capacidad que se encuentra disponible desde MySQL 8.x.x