# ERROR: Error 3522: A primary key index cannot be invisible

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Estoy creando un modelo con **MySQL Workbench 8.0** y mi versión **Target MySQL es la 8.0.18**. Al momento de sincronizar el modelo con la base de datos obtengo el siguiente error:

> ERROR: Error 3522: A primary key index cannot be invisible

pero la linea que marca ese error es la siguiente:

> ````
> SQL Code:
>         ALTER TABLE `database`.`doctors` ALTER INDEX `PRIMARY` VISIBLE
>
> SQL script execution finished: statements: 5 succeeded, 1 failed```
> ````

Entiendo que el error marca que no puede ser **invisible** pero no sé porque esta sucediendo eso

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error 1064 de MySql: creado con MySQL WorkBench](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/285249/error-1064-de-mysql-creado-con-mysql-workbench)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema al generar script sql, ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax;](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/259188/problema-al-generar-script-sql-error-error-1064-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql)